# Seeing strange Question marks in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, locale

I noticed something odd about our RHEL7 servers: in the shell there are always question marks returned, enclosing parts of the text. Kind of like this:

```
rm file.txt
rm: remove regular file ?file.txt??
```

Or this:

`rm 886-
rm: cannot remove ?886-?: No such file or directory`

Is this normal?

I'm ssh-ing from an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop to the RHEL7 servers and using screen. Could this be the source of the differences?

Comment: If you select the wrong encoding in your ssh client then it's normal.

Comment: How can I tell if the wrong encoding is selected? I'm ssh-ing from an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop to the RHEL7 servers and using screen. Could this be the source of the differences?

Comment: Run `locale` command on the remote server and on your desktop and make sure they are using the same encoding. Most likely, one of them is using UTF and the other is using ISO.

Comment: The Ubuntu desktop has `LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"`, while the RHEL 7 servers have `LC_CTYPE="en_NG"` which is very odd because I never set locale when installing the servers. This just started happening recently.

Comment: Open a case at Red Hat's Customer Portal.

Comment: Note that, if you have `rm` aliased to `rm -i`, then the last `?` in the first example is just what it appears to be: the normal response to `rm -i file` is `rm: remove regular empty file ‘file’?`.  As the other responses are trying to say, the quotes are getting garbled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rm` is attempting to display a character that your terminal doesn't support. That's a sign that your [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)) settings are wrong, specifically `LC_CTYPE`. The `LC_CTYPE` environment variable should be set by the terminal emulator and not changed by any script such as `.profile` or `.bashrc`.

You indicate that you're running screen. If you started the screen session in one locale and attach to it in another locale then screen will translate unsupported characters to `?`. It can't change the locale-setting in already-running applications such as the shell that you're running in that window — most applications don't have any support for changing locale settings on the fly. You *can* do it in the shell by setting the `LC_CTYPE` variable. To see what your terminal expects, print the value of `LC_CTYPE` before attaching to the screen session.

To save yourself headaches, adopt consistent locale settings everywhere. Nowadays UTF-8 is the standard everywhere, any other encoding should be used only for compatibility with older applications or devices.

Comment: What's scary is, I don't know how this happened. I don't change locales from the default and everything was fine for as long as I can remember. I noticed this happening a few weeks ago but didn't pay it any attention until subscription-manager and a few other commands started complaining about locale. These servers have been running for a year or two now. Could this be the effects of a compromise?

Comment: @Sina This would be an extremely unlikely symptom of a compromise. It could be a consequence of a configuration change in a number of places (on the client, on the server, in your own configuration files, in system configuration files…). You mention `LC_CTYPE=en_NG`, that has to come from somewhere. Look for the configuration file that sets it and check its history.